# Accessing parent scope from child controller using watch

Tags: angularjs

I have defined $scope variable inside the http.get() method of the Parent Controller. I cant access it directly from child controller because its saying as undefined. When I accessed those scope variable from my Child Controller with using Watch function its working fine. But for more number of scope variables How can I use the watch function?Or else Is another way to do this without using watch? 
I have updated my fiddle here         [click here fiddle for accessing more number of parent scope variables](https://jsfiddle.net/Vijay_Vasu/fc7ofqwz/20/)

```js
    function ParentCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
      
      //  $scope.example1 = $http.get('/echo/json');
        $http.get('/echo/json').then(function(value) {
       $scope.example2 = value.status;
      });
        $http.get('/echo/json/error').then(null,function(value) {
        $scope.example3 = value.status;
        });
        $http.get('/echo/json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.example4 = status;
        });
        $http.get('/echo/json/error').error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.example5 = status;
        });        
        $http.get('/echo/json/error').catch(function(value) {
        $scope.example6 = value.status;
        });        
      
        }
        
    function ChildCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.parentcities = $scope.$parent.cities;
     //   console.log("1=="+$scope.example1);//undefined
        console.log("2=="+$scope.example2);//undefined
        console.log("3=="+$scope.example3);//undefined
        console.log("4=="+$scope.example4);//undefined
        console.log("5=="+$scope.example5);//undefined
        console.log("6=="+$scope.example6);//undefined
        
        
        
         /*$scope.$watch("example1", function(example1) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example1)){
        console.log("1_watch=="+$scope.example1); //Defined 
        }
        });*/
         $scope.$watch("example2", function(example2) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example2)){
        console.log("2_watch=="+$scope.example2); //Defined 
        }
        });
         $scope.$watch("example3", function(example3) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example3)){
        console.log("3_watch=="+$scope.example3); //Defined 
        }
        });
         $scope.$watch("example4", function(example4) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example4)){
        console.log("4_watch=="+$scope.example4); //Defined 
        }
        });
         $scope.$watch("example5", function(example5) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example5)){
        console.log("5_watch=="+$scope.example5); //Defined 
        }
        });
        $scope.$watch("example6", function(example6) {
        if(angular.isDefined(example6)){
        console.log("6_watch=="+$scope.example6); //Defined 
        }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
   <div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
           {{$parent.cities}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your fiddle link is not a hyperlink. can you please edit

Comment: @Maverick can u check now plz  with that click here link

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using watch and $parent in this case.

Events ($broadcast) can be used in parent controller to notify the child controller that the value is retrieved and ready to use.

```
$scope.$broadcast("example1",$scope.example1)  //parent controller

$scope.$on("example1",function(data){
  // Do stuff
}) //child controller
```

My preferred way is to store the data in a factory if it has to be shared across controllers.

If you still need the $watch for some reason you can kill the watch after the data is retrieved so that its no more running. This can be done by using callback returned by $watch().

```
var killExample4 = $scope.$watch("example4", function(example4) {
  if(angular.isDefined(example4)){
    console.log("4_watch=="+$scope.example4); //Defined 
    killExample4();
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I access more number of scope variables in this way???                              var killExample4 = $scope.$watch("example4", function(example4) {
  if(angular.isDefined(example4)){
    console.log("4_watch=="+$scope.example4); //Defined 
    killExample4();
  }
});                         var killExample3 = $scope.$watch("example3", function(example3) {
  if(angular.isDefined(example3)){
    console.log("3_watch=="+$scope.example3); //Defined 
    killExample3();
  }
});          .....etc  Is this the correct way???

Comment: You can keep the variables in factory and inject it in both the controllers

Comment: k will try with angular service